# Creating an Absolute Probability Density Plot from scattered data among different plots

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram, imshow, probability-density

I have six panels of two-dimensional parameter space in the form of a scatter plot as *(x, y)* red dots. I would like to bin x-axis into 7 bins of equal size 0.3. Then I would like to represent probability density in the form of a color-map in which the darkness of each pixel should correspond to the number of dots in the pixel. Here is what I did to create such a color-map using hist2d function. However, as you can see and anticipate, number of dots are not equal (let's say in the darkest pixels among all 7 panels). Therefore, instead, I would like to create a 2d probability density where darkness of the pixel actually obeys an *absolute* scale among all 7 panels. How should I modify my script to get to the point?

Thank you for your help,

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

bins=[7,7]
color_map = mpl.cm.inferno_r
my_range = [[20.3, 22.3], [8, 12]]
tickwidth = 2

relation, (ax14, ax13, ax12, ax11, ax10, ax9, ax8) = plt.subplots(1, 7, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(16,4))

ax8.hist2d(x0, y0, bins=bins, range=my_range, cmap=color_map, weights=None, cmin=None, cmax=None, data=None)

ax8.text(21.1, 11, '$z=0$', fontsize=20)
ax8.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax8.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
ax8.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='upper')) 
ax8.set_xscale("linear", nonposx='clip')
ax8.set_yscale("linear", nonposy='clip')
ax8.xaxis.set_tick_params(width=tick_width)
ax8.yaxis.set_tick_params(width=tick_width)
ax8.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()  


ax9.hist2d(x1, y1, bins=bins, range=my_range, cmap=color_map, weights=None, cmin=None, cmax=None, data=None)

ax9.text(21.1, 11, '$z=0.5$', fontsize=20)
ax9.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax9.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
ax9.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='upper')) 
ax9.set_xscale("linear", nonposx='clip')
ax9.set_yscale("linear", nonposy='clip')
ax9.xaxis.set_tick_params(width=tick_width)
ax9.yaxis.set_tick_params(width=tick_width)
ax9.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()  


ax10.hist2d(x2, y2, bins=bins, range=my_range, cmap=color_map, weights=None, cmin=None, cmax=None, data=None)

ax10.text(21.1, 11, '$z=1$', fontsize=20)
ax10.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax10.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
ax10.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='upper')) 
ax10.set_xscale("linear", nonposx='clip')
ax10.set_yscale("linear", nonposy='clip')
ax10.xaxis.set_tick_params(width=tick_width)
ax10.yaxis.set_tick_params(width=tick_width)
ax10.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()  


ax11.hist2d(x3, y3, bins=bins, range=my_range, cmap=color_map, weights=None, cmin=None, cmax=None, data=None)

ax11.text(21.1, 11, '$z=1.5$', fontsize=20)
ax11.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax11.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
ax11.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='upper')) 
ax11.set_xscale("linear", nonposx='clip')
ax11.set_yscale("linear", nonposy='clip')
ax11.xaxis.set_tick_params(width=tick_width)
ax11.yaxis.set_tick_params(width=tick_width)
ax11.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()  


ax12.hist2d(x4, y4, bins=bins, range=my_range, cmap=color_map, weights=None, cmin=None, cmax=None, data=None)

ax12.text(21.1, 11, '$z=2$', fontsize=20)
ax12.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax12.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
ax12.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='upper')) 
ax12.set_xscale("linear", nonposx='clip')
ax12.set_yscale("linear", nonposy='clip')
ax12.xaxis.set_tick_params(width=tick_width)
ax12.yaxis.set_tick_params(width=tick_width)
ax12.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()  


ax13.hist2d(x5, y5, bins=bins, range=my_range, cmap=color_map, weights=None, cmin=None, cmax=None, data=None)

ax13.text(21.1, 11, '$z=2.5$', fontsize=20)
ax13.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax13.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
ax13.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='upper')) 
ax13.set_xscale("linear", nonposx='clip')
ax13.set_yscale("linear", nonposy='clip')
ax13.xaxis.set_tick_params(width=tick_width)
ax13.yaxis.set_tick_params(width=tick_width)
ax13.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()  


ax14.hist2d(x6, y6, bins=bins, range=my_range, cmap=color_map, weights=None, cmin=None, cmax=None, data=None)

ax14.text(21.1, 11, '$z=3$', fontsize=20)
ax14.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax14.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
ax14.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='upper')) 
ax14.set_xscale("linear", nonposx='clip')
ax14.set_yscale("linear", nonposy='clip')
ax14.xaxis.set_tick_params(width=tick_width)
ax14.yaxis.set_tick_params(width=tick_width)
ax14.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()  
ax14.get_yaxis().tick_left()



relation.subplots_adjust(top=0.979,bottom=0.107,left=0.067,right=0.990)
plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in relation.axes[:-1]], visible=True)
relation.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: scattered plot]
[image: 2D-Histogram]

Comment: Consider setting `vmin/vmax`.

Comment: It's same as cmin and cmax in https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html? What is really the meaning behind these limits?

Comment: If so, I am getting the same dark pixel among all seven panels at the same spot!

Comment: Ok, Yes! I see the difference by choosing cmin, cmax = 5, 50. How would you interpret that? What are your suggestions for the values of these two numbers?

Comment: I was talking about `vmin/vmax`, not `cmin/cmax`. `vmin` should probably be 0, `vmax` should be whatever maximum value you have.

Comment: Thank You, I was confused! Now, makes sense,

Comment: vmax should be the maximum number of red points among all seven panels. Right?

Comment: So, basically my question is each subplot has its own vmax or a single vmax should be chosen for all subplots?

Comment: It seems that I am producing same-color pixels that represent same likelihood. Is there anyway for the colors to be representative of number of dots and not likelihood?